How to use Rmagick with pango and find the correct line width?
Ruby 3.3.2, Rails 7.1.3.3, ImageMagick 7.1.1-33, Rmagick 6.0.1
I use rmagick with pango and I want to calculate the correct number of lines as I'm dynamically selecting the font. In order to correctly calculate the number of rows, I need to know the correct width of the row so that it will fit in my box
draw = Magick::Draw.new
draw.font = 'some_font'
draw.pointsize = 77
current_string = 'sdfgdsfgdfdfgdg sdfg'
metrics = draw.get_type_metrics(current_string)
metrics.width = 722

and it is less than my 800 box, but these 2 words are carried on separate lines.
Also use this variant
temp_image = Magick::Image.new(900, 800)
draw = Magick::Draw.new
draw.font = 'some_font'
draw.pointsize = 77
current_string = 'sdfgdsfgdfdfgdg sdfg'
metrics = draw.get_type_metrics(temp_image, current_string)
metrics.width = 722

the same.
Method get_multiline_type_metrics to calculate the total height I can't use, because it separates \n, but my text without \n and I can't set \n because I try to define dynamic font_size. And to set \n, you need to know the correct line width.
The main problem is that the metrics show the size that should fit, but the text is moved. This does not work in all cases, in most cases it is calculated correctly.
I must add that
I carry out the calculations through
Magick::Image.read("pango:sdfgdsfgdfdfgdg sdfg") do |img|
  img.size = box_size
  img.background_color = 'none'
  img.pointsize = font_size
  img.font = 'some font'
  img.fill = 'white'
  img.gravity = gravity
  img.define('pango', 'markup', 'false')
end

and check the row width via
draw = Magick::Draw.new
draw.font = 'some_font'
draw.pointsize = 77
current_string = 'sdfgdsfgdfdfgdg sdfg'
metrics = draw.get_type_metrics(current_string)
metrics.width = 722

I expected that these two words should be on the same line, based on the length that rmagick gives me in the parameters.enter image description here

Calculate the Text Width for Each Line:Instead of relying on get_type_metrics, you can manually calculate the width of each line by splitting the text and checking if it fits within the desired width.Then,Render the text onto a temporary image to visually confirm the fitting and calculate the number of lines. Also,Dynamically adjust the font size based on the text length and the box dimensions

to calculate the length of the line in pixels, it is correct to use get_type_metrics because this is the method provided by rmagick. My problem was wrongly cached background images. Cleared the cache and everything worked! Thanks for the advice!
